# React Native: Dynamically disable/enable screen rotation

Tags: react-native

I know that I can control the screen rotation statically in React Native through Android.Manifest for Android and through Xcode for iOS. But I need a dynamic solution. Here is a pseudo-code of what I want to achieve:

```
isTablet ? enableRotation() : disableRotation ();
```

How can I enable/disable rotation dynamically for specific screen?